# Remove group rows

Tags: pandas

How do I remove group rows based on other columns for a particular ID such that:

```
ID    Att    Comp Att.   Inc. Att
aaa    2        0           2
aaa    2        0           2
bbb    3        1           2
bbb    3        1           2
bbb    3        0           2
```

becomes:

```
ID    Att    Comp Att.   Inc. Att
aaa    2        0           2
bbb    3        1           2
```

I need to discard cases which are not just duplicate, but also infer the same data based on the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` --  check out the documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

I can't tell for sure from your description what you want to pay attention for for duplicates, but you can tell `drop_duplicates` which column(s) to look at.